# KVM firewall to disallow internet access for group of guests

Tags: networking, iptables, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, bridge

I've got a KVM server inside a local network (192.168.10.0/24). This server has three interfaces, which are all publicly bridged [1]. Atm I'm only using two of the three interfaces, so the virtual machines are divided into two groups (one using *bridge0*, the other one using *bridge1*).

Is it possible to setup a firewall (iptables) on the **host**, to disallow internet access for the group using *bridge1*? Or do I need a different setup (routing through the host)?

[1] http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking#public_bridge

---

I tried the following (but doesn't seem to work):

1. allow everything over local loopback
2. allow everything over *bridge0*
3. allow only local network traffic over *bridge1*
4. deny everything else

The corresponding `iptables -S` output:

```
    -P INPUT DROP
    -P FORWARD DROP
    -P OUTPUT DROP
    -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i lo -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -i bridge0 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -i bridge1 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -j DROP 
    -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
    -A FORWARD -i bridge0 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A FORWARD -o bridge0 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A FORWARD -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -i bridge1 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A FORWARD -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -o bridge1 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A FORWARD -j DROP 
    -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
    -A OUTPUT -o lo -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A OUTPUT -o bridge0 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -o bridge1 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
    -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set 2 iptables rules on the host, one allowing access to the internet from bridge0 and the other denying access to internet for every one else, using the --in-interface / --out-interface parameters.

Comment: One of the things I tried was the code I added to my question (just now), but didn't seem to work. Is this what you mean? Or am I missing something?